# Can't update remote maven repositories index

Tags: maven, indexing, intellij-idea, nexus, repository

I deploy the lastest nexus on Linux server, nexus version is 2.11.2-06. After I start Nexus on linux server I can access nexus via a browser with url http://ip:port/nexus. Then I want to create maven project in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.6. After I create the project I want to update maven repository index at `Settings -> Maven -> Repositories -> Indexed Maven Repositories` window. I always get error after I click update button:

> FileNotFoundException: nexus-maven-repository-index.zip not found

will pop up when I pointer over maven repo url in this window, I have search for the answer for couple of days, It seems like many people were troubled in this problem, Is there any one know exactly how to fix this problem? any help will appreciate.

my local settings.xml under user/.m2/ content as follow:

```
    <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
      <url>http://linux_server_ip:8091/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>   

  </mirrors>


  <profiles>
    <profile>  
        <id>nexus</id>  
        <repositories>  
             <repository>  
               <id>nexus-releases</id>  
               <url>http://central</url>  
              <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>  
               <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>  
             </repository>  
             <repository>  
               <id>nexus-snapshots</id>  
               <url>http://central</url>  
               <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>  
               <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>  
             </repository>  
           </repositories>  
           <pluginRepositories>  
              <pluginRepository>  
                     <id>nexus-releases</id>  
                      <url>http://central</url>  
                      <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>  
                      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>  
                    </pluginRepository>  
                    <pluginRepository>  
                      <id>nexus-snapshots</id>  
                       <url>http://central</url>  
                     <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>  
                      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>  
                  </pluginRepository>  
              </pluginRepositories>  
        </profile>
  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
```

In my idea maven repositories window:

URL                         Type    updated
C:/Users/1/.m2/repository   Local   2015/5/21
http://central              Remote  Error
pop msg is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resources nexus-maven-repository-index.zip does not exist.

Comment: You need to configured nexus to create the index and publish the index. How this can be done can be extracted from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `setting.xml` file to your `.m2` folder.